# JPanel is only a black square when maximize the window and the JPanel is too big

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

im a Java beginner and i'm working on a programm which is almost done and does this:

1. Reads the adress of an image via the command line and loads the
   image
2. save the image as an array of RGB values
3. opens the frame

The user can press 3 buttons which display the loaded image in different ways (Original, Grayscale, Pattern) and press one button to exit the application.

The size of the loaded image gets doubled (so one pixel of the original image is a 2x2 square in the shown image).

My problem: when the image(/JPanel) is too big for the screen and the user maximizes the window, the image is only a little black square.

Is there a way i can set the behavior, that the image is only shown partially?

My code:

```
package uebung;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


/**
 * Klasse die das Erzeugen des Fensters ermöglicht (Konstruktor, Listener, JPanel-Klassen).
 * 
 * @author Christoph Lehmann
 * @version 1.0 (13.06.2015)
 */
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    /**
     * Panel für den Bild-Container für die zentrierte Anzeige der Bild-Panels
     */
    JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    /**
     * Container der drei Bild-Panels
     */
    JPanel panelCont = new JPanel();

    /**
     * Originaldarstellung des Bildes
     */
    JPanel panelOriginal = new DrawOriginal();

    /**
     * Graustufendarstellung des Bildes
     */
    JPanel panelGrayscale = new DrawGrayscale();

    /**
     * Musterdarstellung des Bildes
     */
    JPanel panelPattern = new DrawPattern();

    /**
     *  Einreihung der oberen Buttons
     */
    JPanel panelTop = new JPanel(); 

    /**
     *  Einreihung des unteren Buttons
     */
    JPanel panelBot = new JPanel(); 

    /**
     *  Darstellung der drei Bild-Panels
     */
    CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();

    /**
     * Wechseln zum Originalbild
     */
    JButton buttonOriginal = new JButton ("Original");

    /**
     * Wechseln zum Graustufenbild
     */
    JButton buttonGrayscale = new JButton ("Grayscale");

    /**
     * Wechseln zum Musterbild
     */
    JButton buttonPattern = new JButton ("Pattern");

    /**
     * Beenden der Anwendung
     */
    JButton buttonExit = new JButton ("Exit");

    /**
     * Erkennt das Drücken der Buttons
     */
    MyActionListener myActionListener = new MyActionListener();

    /**
     * Breite des eingelesenen Bildes
     */
    int w = DrawPicture.image.getWidth();

    /**
     * Höhe des eingelesenen Bildes
     */
    int h = DrawPicture.image.getHeight();

    /**
     * Array mit RGB-Werten jedes einzelenen Pixels des eingelesenen Bildes
     */
    int [][] RGB = DrawPicture.imageRGB;

    /**
     * Farbe beim Zeichnen in den inneren Panelklassen
     */
    Color c;

    /**
     * Erzeugt das Fenster und seine Komponenten
     */
    public MyFrame(String title, int width, int height) {
        super(title);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width*2+30, height*2+120)); //+20 und +120 sind vage Werte für die Bereiche der Buttons oben und unten
        setLocation(30,30); //nicht direkt in der Ecke aber oben links
        setVisible(true);

        //Einrichten des Containers mit CardLayout
        panelCont.setLayout(cl);
        panelCont.add(panelOriginal, "O");
        panelCont.add(panelGrayscale, "G");
        panelCont.add(panelPattern, "P");
        cl.show(panelCont,"O");
        content.add(panelCont); //GradBagLayout -> Bild-Panels werden zentriert
        add(content);

        //Einrichten der Panels für die Buttons im FlowLayout (für links und rechts)
        panelTop.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelBot.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        add(panelBot, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Hinzufügen der Buttons + Zuweisen der Listener
        buttonOriginal.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        panelTop.add(buttonOriginal);
        buttonGrayscale.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        panelTop.add(buttonGrayscale);
        buttonPattern.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        panelTop.add(buttonPattern);
        buttonExit.addActionListener(myActionListener);
        panelBot.add(buttonExit);

        pack();
    }

    /**
     * Listener für die vier Buttons Original, Grayscale, Pattern und Exit
     */
    class MyActionListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //e.getSource ermöglicht die Verwendung eines einzigen Listeners, anstatt für jeden Button einen eigenen erzeugen zu müssen
            if (e.getSource() == buttonExit){ 
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (e.getSource() == buttonOriginal){
                //durch cl.show kommt das CardLayout zum Einsatz, damit alle 3 Bildpanels übereinander gelegt werden aber abwechselnd angezeigt werden können
                cl.show(panelCont,"O"); 
            } 
            else if (e.getSource() == buttonGrayscale){
                cl.show(panelCont,"G");
            } 
            else if (e.getSource() == buttonPattern){
                cl.show(panelCont,"P");
            } 
        }   
    }

    /**
     * Klasse für die Darstellung des Bildes im Original.
     */
    class DrawOriginal extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
             return new Dimension (w*2 ,h*2);
         }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //alle Pixel des eingelesenen Bildes (anhand des RGB-Arrays) werden durchlaufen
            for (int i=0; i<w;i++){
                for (int k=0; k<h;k++){
                    c= new Color(RGB[i][k]);
                    g.setColor(c); 
                    //da das zu zeichnende Bild doppelt so groß werden muss, stellen die zu zeichnenden Koordinaten die Originalkoordinaten mal zwei dar
                    int x=i*2;
                    int y=k*2;
                    //ein Rechteck der Größe 2x2 wird in der eingelesenen Farbe (=der Farbe des Originals) gezeichnet
                    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                    g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                    g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                    g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Klasse für die Darstellung des Bildes in Graustufen.
     */
    class DrawGrayscale extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
             return new Dimension (w*2 ,h*2);
         }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //alle Pixel des eingelesenen Bildes (anhand des RGB-Arrays) werden durchlaufen
            for (int i=0; i<w;i++){
                for (int k=0; k<h;k++){
                    c= new Color(RGB[i][k]);
                    //die einzelnen Farbwerte werden ausgelesen
                    int red = c.getRed();
                    int green = c.getGreen();
                    int blue = c.getBlue();
                    //der Mittelwert wird bestimmt
                    int avg = (red + green + blue)/3;
                    //die verwendete Farbe ist nun ein Grauwert
                    c = new Color(avg, avg, avg);
                    g.setColor(c); 
                    //da das zu zeichnende Bild doppelt so groß werden muss, stellen die zu zeichnenden Koordinaten die Originalkoordinaten mal zwei dar
                    int x=i*2;
                    int y=k*2;
                    //ein Rechteck der Größe 2x2 wird in der entsprechenden Graustufe gezeichnet
                    g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                    g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                    g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                    g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Klasse für die Darstellung des Bildes in Musterform.
     */
    class DrawPattern extends JPanel {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize () {
             return new Dimension (w*2 ,h*2);
         }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            //alle Pixel des eingelesenen Bildes (anhand des RGB-Arrays) werden durchlaufen
            for (int i=0; i<w;i++){
                for (int k=0; k<h;k++){
                    c= new Color(RGB[i][k]);
                    //die einzelnen Farbwerte werden ausgelesen
                    int red = c.getRed();
                    int green = c.getGreen();
                    int blue = c.getBlue();
                    //der Mittelwert wird bestimmt
                    int avg = (red + green + blue)/3;
                    // es werden die Farben Schwarz und Weiß für den Zeichenvorgang zur Verfügung gestellt
                    Color white = new Color(0, 0, 0);
                    Color black = new Color(255, 255, 255);
                    //da das zu zeichnende Bild doppelt so groß werden muss, stellen die zu zeichnenden Koordinaten die Originalkoordinaten mal zwei dar
                    int x=i*2;
                    int y=k*2;
                    //je nachdem welcher Mittelwert für den Originalpixel bestimmt wird, wird eines der fünf zu zeichnenden 2x2 Rechtecke gewählt
                    // w= white b=black
                    if (avg<=50){
                        // w w
                        // w w
                        g.setColor(white);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                        g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);
                    }
                    else if (avg >=51 && avg<=101){
                        // b w
                        // w w
                        g.setColor(black);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);

                        g.setColor(white);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                        g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);
                    } 
                    else if (avg >=102 && avg<=152){
                        // b w
                        // w b
                        g.setColor(black);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);

                        g.setColor(white);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                        g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                    } 
                    else if (avg >=153 && avg<=203){
                        // w b
                        // b b
                        g.setColor(black);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                        g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);

                        g.setColor(white);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                    }
                    else {
                        // b b
                        // b b
                        g.setColor(black);
                        g.drawLine(x, y, x, y);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y, x+1, y);
                        g.drawLine(x, y+1, x, y+1);
                        g.drawLine(x+1, y+1, x+1, y+1);         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Anwendung die das Bild aus der Kommandozeile ausliest, das Bild in einem intRGB-Array speichert und das Fenster öffnet.
 */
public class DrawPicture {

    static BufferedImage image = null;
    static int [][] imageRGB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Bitte geben sie den Pfad des gewünschten Bildes ein.\nMit der Eingabe von EXIT können sie die Eingabe abbrechen und das Programm beenden.");
        System.out.print("Pfad: ");

        String path = "";

        //verlangt so lange eine Eingabe vom Nutzer, bis erfolgreich ein Bild eingelsen wurde, oder der Nutzer die Eingabe abbricht
        while (true) {
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                path = bufferRead.readLine();

                if (path.equals("EXIT")){
                    System.exit(0);
                }

                image = ImageIO.read(DrawPicture.class.getResource(path));
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) { //IOException, InvalidArgumentException, ...
                System.out.println("Das Bild konnte nicht geladen werden. Versuchen sie es erneut.");
                System.out.print("Pfad: ");
            }
        }

        //Speichert das eingelesene Bild in einem Array (RGB-Werte)
        imageRGB = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];

        for (int x=0; x<image.getWidth();x++){
            for (int y=0; y<image.getHeight();y++){
                imageRGB[x][y]=image.getRGB(x, y);
            }
        }

        //öffnet das Fenster
        new MyFrame("DrawPicture", image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    }
}
```

Here are two images:

[**Startup**](http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150623/evxobsyz.jpg)

[**Maximized windows:**](http://fs2.directupload.net/images/150623/7fhsyi9k.jpg)

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to display the image in original size or scaled with the underlying component (e.g. `JPanel`) ? Also if your image is too large, you might want to take a look at [JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

Comment: Hello, i want to display the image in original size. The solution of Fast Snail worked, but now the image is not centered anymore in the middle of the window (which was the reason i tried the GridBagLayout thing) ... JScrollPane look like an interesting solution. I'll have a look at this now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix this problem change this

```
JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); // about line 30
```

to this

```
JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
```

---

the problem is this line

```
JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());//
```

and this line

```
content.add(panelCont);
```

this is not the correct way of adding components to `gridBag layout`

since you should show entire `panelCont` inside `content` panel i changed gridbag layout to `new GridLayout(1, 1)` and problem solved .

anyway if you want to use gridbag layout read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: Thanks you :) I see, i messed around with the GridBagLayout. Is there a way to center my panelCont in the middle of the frame without using the GridBagLayout, so when i resize the window, the images still stay at the center?

Comment: @Xyarvius i'm not much familiar with swing layouts but i will check and tell you how to center it

Comment: Use a BorderLayout:   add( thingToCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER )

Comment: I used that before, but it didn't work. The images are still at the top left of the window below the buttons. (i changed "JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());" to "JPanel content = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());"  and "add(content)" to "add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);" ... it didnt work :(

Comment: Well, i found a solution. I set "JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());" to "JPanel content = new JPanel();" and it worked. The images are shown in the center all time. But i dont know why ... can someone explain me?

Comment: @Xyarvius jpanel has default layout `flowLayout` .so same as `Panel content = new JPanel(new FlowLayout())`